# How do I fix this carousel?

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out why this code wont work. I've pieced together two codes from w3 to make an automatic carousel with buttons and indicators for which slide you are on. Does anyone have an idea whats wrong? it only has the buttons working.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ad-img");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-white";
}
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  plusDivs(1)
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none
}

.w3-left,
.w3-right,
.w3-badge {
  cursor: pointer
}

.w3-badge {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2 class="w3-center">
    Check out these Sweet Deals!</h2>
</div>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:769px">
  {{banners:types=\Theater_769x300\;start=1;count=7;order=random}}
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">
      ❮</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">
      ❯</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited your post, making a runnable snippet of your code. If you inspect it, you will see that it stalls on trying to get an element with a className of `ad-img`.

Comment: First and most glaring issue is that you don't have any elements for `ad-img`

Comment: Take a look at these (might be helpful): https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/

Comment: I'm super new at writing these things. I got hired at a job that needs me to do this. So what do i need to do specifically?